# number of days calculation in javascript

Tags: javascript, excel, date

I have problem in number of days calculation in Java Script some time JS will correct but some time different number of days between excel and javascript.

this is my javascript

```
var date1 = new Date(date_time);//first granded date
var date2 = new Date(redeem_date);//today date
var date3 = new Date(last_pdate);//last payment date
var difference1 = Math.abs(date1 - date2);
var difference2 = Math.abs(date1 - date3);
var difference = difference1-difference2;
var one_day = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24;
var period= Math.round(difference/one_day);
```

this is excel file screen shot.

[image: Excel File Screen Shot]

Comment: I'm not seeing your console.log output in the JavaScript code.  What's not working? and how do you know XL is correct?

Comment: This is about excel format problem ! Not so relative with javascript

Comment: You need to explain what you expected to get, what you actually get and any error messages. Posting code and saying "sometimes it's wrong" is pointless. Also, not everyone can see posted images (for various reasons) so post text, not images.

Comment: Excel is correct because PHP Calculation is also calculate correctly. problem not solved. in javascript problem is round 1.1 = 1, 1.4 = 1, 1.0 = 1 but its need to come 1.1 = 2, 1.0 = 1, 1.25 = 2 like this, if second decimal place is o it should be same if second decimal is grater than 0 it should be round up the amount.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `Math.round`, consider using `Math.ceil`.

This is assuming that any moment past the start of a day starts a new one.

i.e.

1.1 Days => 2 Days

Comment: This should be a comment.

Comment: I don't have 50 reputation

Comment: you are correct but what is solution for this. PHP and excel is correct. mathl.ceil also tried